# Is there any easy way to find function from laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I am developing an Application in **laravel** for that I am using IDE (***visual studio code***). I am using the laravel controller. I wrote more than 50 function-related to that controller in one single controller. My problem is if I want to change something in one function, I want to find that function from a lot of codes. So that finding the function is very difficult for me. Please anyone says how can I easily find that function?

Currently, I am using ctrl+f and search that function name in visual studio code. But I think it is not the best way.

Comment: just `ctrl+f` and search for the function name

Comment: I know this one. other than that any simple one? For example, if you are using netbeans it shows all functions name in the one of sidebar like that anything?

Comment: dude `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called **Refactoring** so you can search :

**How refactor code in VSCode**

Follow this [link](https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/)

> When you are looking at your code and you want to find where a function or variable is defined, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to navigate to the definition. This works in the same file or to another file when using TypeScript.

Comment: `ctrl` + `left click` on a function should also either peek the definition or go to the definition (if it's in the same file).

Comment: Sorry, Actually I missed out your answer. Thanks for your time, It's not an answer to my question. My question is different please read the question again then I guess you will get the best understand.